# Orthogonality of Bessel functions of different types

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

Is there a way to (at least partially) integrate a combination of Bessel functions like:

$$\int_0^{\infty}J_m(b x)- \frac{J_m(a x)}{H_m^{(1)}(a x)}H_m^{(1)}(b x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Since $H_m^{(1)}(x)H_m^{(2)}(x)=J_m^2(x)+Y_m^2(x)$, I tried to use identities like: [(19) in paragraph 19.3 of table of integral transforms by Bateman (see http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/)], which reads:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(a x)Y_0(b x)-J_0(b x)Y_0(a x)}{J_0^2(b x)+Y_0^2(b x)}\frac{x}{\lambda^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{H_\nu^{(2)}(a\lambda)}{H_\nu^{(2)}(b\lambda)}$$

Unfortunately this particular one seems to be wrong and I wasn't able to spot the error. Has anyone out there seen similar relations or integral representation of reciprocal Bessel function (of third kind) or knows an erratum for the equation above?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Comment: $\int_0^\infty J_m(x)\,dx=1$.  So, now you need only worry about $\int_0^\infty \frac{J_m(ax)}{H^{(1)}(ax)}\,H^{(1)}(bx)\,dx$

Comment: Yes in deed :) 
I added the single $J_m$ only to indicate the vanishing boundary condition that appears for $a=b$. But it is actually irrelevant for the problem at hands.